# How can I obtain port binding information at runtime? (JBoss 5.1)

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jboss5.x

Basically what I want to do is to obtain the port number on which JBoss is listening for HTTP requests (the one that is normally 8080).

I came upon this [article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ServiceBindingManagerManagementInterface), which sounds promising, but unfortunately some of the links are broken and I cannot figure out the part:

```
ManagementView managementView = getManagementView(); // via JNDI lookup
```

How could I implement getManagementView()? Or is there any other preferable way to do it?

Comment: Working with JBoss is so much easier if you leave the ports as they are, and use multiple IP addresses instead.

Comment: Um, okay, I think I found something: http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/branches/Branch_5_0/testsuite/src/main/org/jboss/test/profileservice/test/AbstractProfileServiceTest.java

Comment: Also mentioned here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ProfileService

Comment: The method cited in the above url (the unit tests from jboss source) appears to be not working  for 5.1 (Or maybe I am screwing up). Opted to have a config file that must be kept in sync with the actual port number (per hand). Help is still appreciated though!

Comment: @skaffman What do you mean - "multiple IP addresses".
Is there any tutorial about it?

Comment: @Vladimir: If your machine has multiple IP addresses, then you can bind JBoss to a specific one using `-b <ip>` when you start JBoss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I decided what to do.

Obtaining port information at runtime is cumbersome. An easy alternative is to have a config file that must be kept in sync with the actual port number (per hand). Not very clever but it saves you a bunch of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simpler interface, you might want to consider using their command line tool called [Twiddle](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle).

It is powerful command line based tool and doesn't require any Java coding.  It can be leveraged from any scripting language (bash, perl, ruby, etc...).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't actually address the problem, though.

Comment: Yeah, I need to access it through java, programmatically. Thanks though.

Comment: ./twiddle.sh serverinfo -l | grep "jboss.web:type=Connector"  will return the port.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to access it from inside the application deployed on the JBoss. I wouldn't want to roll out runtime.exec or something for this..