# Obtain the $JBOSS_HOME/bin value in JBoss 4.2.x

Tags: jboss

Calling the JBoss command line tool [Twiddle](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle), located in *$JBOSS_HOME\bin directory*, can give us the port number on which JBoss is listening for HTTP requests (see [Q2366489](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366489/how-can-i-obtain-port-binding-information-at-runtime-jboss-5-1)).  That's smashing :)

However, we can't rely on the fact that the system administrator has set the JBOSS_HOME path variable, and it would be useful to know if we can obtain this directory programatically from within the JBoss environment.  In my case the project is deployed as a WAR file.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, and various other path-related values, are set by JBoss as system properties, which you should use to obtain them.

For example, the system property `jboss.home.dir` will be set to the equivalent of `$JBOSS_HOME`, regardless of how the server is actually started.

The various system properties are defined in `org.jboss.system.server.ServerConfig`.

So:

```
String jbossHomeDir = System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir");
```